# LINQ Select within a Select

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to query a collection that contains **Employee** information. When I query that collection I would like to return an enumeration of objects where each object has two fields:

- Name
- ManagerName

(Note that every Manager is also an Employee!)

Now, here's the problem I am having. When I do a `select` within a `select`, the value of the `ManagerName` field that is returned on each object is:

```
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.CompensatingCollection<string>
```

Here's the query:

```cs
var query =
    from e in db.Employees    
    select new
    {
        Name = e.Name,
        ManagerName =
            from em2 in db.Employees
            where (em2.EmployeeID == e.ManagerID)
            select em2.Name
    };
```

Specifically, when I look at the value of `ManagerName`, I see that it is an enumeration that yields a single item. And that the single item is a string that contains the name of the Manager. So, I think I'm close.

**Question:** How can I change my query so that instead it returns an enumeration of objects where each object simply has two string fields, `Name` and `ManagerName`?

Comment: What result do you want and what result do you have now? Don't you have now a collection pair of strings in `query` variable?

Comment: Now I have:
obj.Name = "MyName";
obj.ManagerName 
 = System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.CompensatingCollection

and only inside that object it has the "MyManagerName"

I want:
obj.Name = "MyName";
obj.ManagerName = "MyManagerName";

Comment: And what do you want to get?

Comment: When you say "two fields" do you mean two *records*?  Currently the inner `select` is only selecting a single field, but it's selecting an enumeration of that field for any matching records (which could be zero or more).  Changing two fields on a single record into a single field is easy, but if you're talking about combining multiple records into a single field then there's probably more logic that needs to be applied.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = from e in db.Employees
            select new
            {
                Name = e.Name,
                ManagerName = db.Employees
                                .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == e.ManagerID)
                                .Select(x => x.Name).SingleOrDefault()
            };
```

However, if you correctly mapped your database with [EF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/entity-framework/info) (which I suppose you are using), you should have a navigation property you can utilize:

```
var query = from e in db.Employees
            select new
            {
                Name = e.Name,
                ManagerName = e.Manager.Name
            };
```

Comment: It worked but I had to change to FirstOrDefault or I was getting this error:
{"The methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead."}

Comment: I still didn't understand what does topic starter want :(

Comment: @FSou1: He simply wants to have the name of the manager for each selected employee.

Comment: But why didn't he have it with his query =\ Its look like good

Comment: @FSou1: The result is a list with one entry. He needed just that entry (without it being in a list). That's what FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault are there for.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a self-join should work:

```
var query = from e in db.Employees
            join m in db.Employees on e.ManagerID equals m.EmployeeID
              select new
              {
                Name = e.Name,
                ManagerName = m.Name
              };
```

Comment: I think you need to use `equals` instead of `=` in the join condition.