# How to use join in Entity Framework to make output Json objects in levels - not the same level

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, nested

I am trying to fetch data from a SQL Server database.

The database has 3 tables as shown here:

[image]

The tables relate to each other using primary and foreign key:

- HALAQATI_View_GetAllMosques (Parent)
- HALAQATI_View_GetAllRings   (Child)
- HALAQATI_View_GetAllStudents (Child Of Child)

Code:

```
var result = (from m in db.HALAQATI_VIEW_GetAllMosques
     join r in db.HALAQATI_VIEW_GetAllRings on m.MSQ_ID equals r.MSQ_ID
     join s in db.HALAQATI_VIEW_GetAllStudents on r.Ring_ID equals s.Ring_ID
     where m.Emp_ID == r.Emp_ID && m.Emp_ID == id
     select new { MsqID = m.MSQ_ID, MsqName = m.MSQ_Name, Rings = r,Students = s}).Distinct();
return new { Mosques = result };
```

The output appears like this

```
{
  "Mosques": [
    {
      "MsqID": 186,
      "MsqName": "UNIVERSITY 1",
      "Rings": {
        "Ring_ID": 3730,
        "Ring_Name": "Class 1",
        "MSQ_ID": 186,
        "Emp_ID": 3750
      },
      "Students": {
        "Student_ID": 80065,
        "Student_Name": "Student 1",
        "Ring_ID": 3730
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that `Rings` And `Students` appear on the same level in the Json and that's wrong.

The `students` must come under the `Rings`.

The expected result must be like this:

```
{
  "Mosques": [
    {
      "MsqID": 186,
      "MsqName": "UNIVERSITY 1",
      "Rings": [
        {
          "Ring_ID": 3730,
          "Ring_Name": "Class 1",
          "MSQ_ID": 186,
          "Emp_ID": 3750,
          "Students": [
            {
              "Student_ID": 80065,
              "Student_Name": "Student 1",
              "Ring_ID": 3730
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `select new { MsqID = m.MSQ_ID, MsqName = m.MSQ_Name, Rings = r,Students = s})` Unless Rings has a Students property, you are explicitly declaring it at the same level as Rings, not as a sub-object of Rings. Looks like you need an inner select somewhere in your LINQ.

Comment: @RonBeyer EXACTLY, That's What i want, i tried a lot but nothing works tell now. do you have a solution?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841108/linq-select-within-a-select Try searching for "linq inner select" and read some of the answers, there seems to be a number of ways to do it and without having a setup just like yours I can't recommend a good way to do it.

Comment: It may be as simple as `select new { MsqID = m.MSQ_ID, MsqName = m.MSQ_Name, Rings = new { Ring = r, Students = s } }` I've never tried to create an anonymous type within another anonymous type so I'm not sure if that will work. The issue is that you want Rings to be an array, not a single type so I'm not sure how to express that.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks for your effort, but it's not working As Expected still waiting for the solution :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is roughly the pattern you need. Don't worry about doing the JOINs yourself: let the framework take care of joining tables, while you think of the shape of that data you're looking for.

```
var result = 
     from m in db.HALAQATI_VIEW_GetAllMosques
     where m.Emp_ID == id
     select new {
         MsqID = m.MSQ_ID,
         MsqName = m.MSQ_Name, 
         Rings = from r in db.HALAQATI_VIEW_GetAllRings
             where m.MSQ_ID == r.MSQ_ID
             where m.Emp_ID == r.Emp_ID  // is this even necessary?
             select new {
                 r.Ring_ID,
                 ...
                 Students = from s in db.HALAQATI_VIEW_GetAllStudents
                     where r.Ring_ID == s.Ring_ID
                     select s
             }
     };
return new { Mosques = result };
```

Comment: Thanks, That's want i want exactly.

Comment: what if i want to make a properity equals to a stored proc. result. ?