# SQL Server query into LINQ Query

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2012

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to make this query into a LINQ statement.  I don't even know where to begin.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TestRFRVWL x
WHERE x.TestPALID IN
(SELECT
   a.TestPALID
 FROM
   dbo.GroupID(nolock) a
     INNER JOIN
     dbo.CustomPAl(nolock) b ON
   a.TestPALID = b.TestPALID
 WHERE GroupID LIKE '%A12345%'
);
```

Comment: Try reading up on LINQ.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693024.aspx

Comment: Try this for your query which will make your LINQ statement easier: `SELECT
  x.*
FROM
  dbo.GroupID(nolock) a
    INNER JOIN
    dbo.CustomPAl(nolock) b ON
  a.TestPALID = b.TestPALID
    INNER JOIN
    TestRFRVWL x ON
  x.TestPALID = a.TestPALID
WHERE GroupID LIKE '%A12345%';`

Comment: After you've gained an understanding of LINQ with @Neil's suggestion, look at questions here [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841108/linq-select-within-a-select) that deal with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

A close to literal translation looks something like:

```
from x in TestRFRVWL
where (from a in GroupID
       join b in CustomPAl
       on a.TestPALID equals b.TestPALID
       select a.TestPALID).Contains(x.TestPALID)
select x;
```

Given that you aren't really using the join for joining, I might prefer something like:

```
from x in TestRFRVWL
where dbo.GroupID.Any(a => a.TestPalID == x.TestPalID) &&
      dbo.CustomPAl.Any(b => b.TestPalID == x.TestPalID)
select x;
```

Or even something in method syntax:

```
TestRFRVWL.Where(x => dbo.GroupID.Select(a => a.TestPalID).Contains(x.TestPalID) &&
                      dbo.CustomPAl.Select(b => b.TestPalID).Contains(x.TestPalID))
```

but I'm not sure which generates the best SQL.